# window.location is not working with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need:

- I need to redirect the page to specified urls.

html code:

```
      <li>
            <input type="radio" checked="" id="radio1" name="radioButton" data-filter=".radio2" class="filter">
            <label for="radio1" class="radio-label" id="shows" value="htttp://abc.com/a" onclick="make_url(1)" >All E</label>
          </li>


          <li>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioButton" data-filter=".radio3" class="filter">
            <label for="radio2" class="radio-label" value="htttp://abc.com/s" id="shows" onclick="make_url(2)">Trades</label>
          </li>
```

js code

```
function make_url(val) {
    event_type = val;

    if (event_type == 1) {
        window.document.location.href = "/e";

        return false
    } else if (event_type == 2) {
        window.document.location.href = "/tras";
        return false
    }
}
```

My Problem:

- When I click on radio buttons somtimes it works sometimes it doesn't.
- click on radio button is not working.

Comment: Could you be a little more detailed about what happens?

Comment: Is that formatting correct? value=""htttp://abc.com/a" Because that may break the DOM and make you not able to click on anything

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cfmlprabhu/y661v4h9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I must suggest a cleaner approach, don't call functions using an onclick attribute. Make use of event bubbling. Capture bubbled events and do whatever you need to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
 $('#radioButtons').on('click', function(e){
  var value = $(e.target).attr('value');
  if(value){
   someFunction(value)
  }
 });
});


function someFunction(value){
  // Do something with the value. 
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="radioButtons" class="list-unstyled">
    <li><input type="radio" value="1"> <label for="">Radio Btn 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="2"> <label for="">Radio Btn 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="3"> <label for="">Radio Btn 3</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="4"> <label for="">Radio Btn 4</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="5"> <label for="">Radio Btn 5</label></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a sample: http://jsbin.com/leyuxolozi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry about that. Updated my answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the click event to radio button instead of giving it for label. Because of `for` attribute of the label, that click event of radio button bound to corresponding label also.

Try this code snippet:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" checked="" id="radio1" name="radioButton" data-filter=".radio2" onclick="make_url(1)" class="filter">
        <label for="radio1" class="radio-label" id="shows" value="htttp://abc.com/a">All E</label>
    </li>


    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioButton" data-filter=".radio3" onclick="make_url(2)" class="filter">
        <label for="radio2" class="radio-label" value="htttp://abc.com/s" id="shows" >Trades</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

First give the onclick event to the radio button:

```
 <ul>
   <li>
    <input type="radio" checked="" id="radio1" name="radioButton" data-filter=".radio2" class="filter" onclick="make_url(1)" >
    <label for="radio1" class="radio-label" id="shows" value="htttp://abc.com/a" >All E</label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioButton" data-filter=".radio3" class="filter" onclick="make_url(2)">
    <label for="radio2" class="radio-label" value="htttp://abc.com/s" id="shows" >Trades</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Then change the make_url() function like this:

```
function make_url(val) {
  event_type = val;
  if (event_type == 1) {
     window.location = "/e";
  } 
  else if (event_type == 2) {
    window.location = "/tras";
  }
}
```